# How to read a specific line in txt file vb 6

Tags: vb6

I would like to read a specific line in a .txt file in a vb 6.0 program. My intrest is where a particular line where a certain text appears. I am trying to apply this code which I got from another project.

```
Dim strLine As String
Open "E:\Projects\VB\Ubunifu\MyList.txt" For Input As #1
Line Input #1, strLine ' read one line at a time vs entire file
lblCurrent.Caption = strLine
Line Input #1, strLine
lblO.Caption = strLine
Close #1
```

however this doesnt seem to be working it says "input past end of file"

Comment: Your code reads 2 lines.  If the file has less than two lines then of course you would be going "past end of file."  If your file isn't encoded as ANSI with CR or CRLF as line delimiters that could also cause a problem.  In such a case you must do something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()
       Text1.MultiLine = True
       Open "E:\Projects\VB\Ubunifu\MyList.txt" For Input As #1
       Text1.Text = Input$(LOF(1), #1)

       lblCurrent.Caption = udf_ReadLine(Text1.Text, 1)   ' read line #1
       lblCurrent_i.Caption = udf_ReadLine(Text1.Text, 2)   ' read line #2

       Close #1
    End Sub

    Private Function udf_ReadLine(ByVal sDataText As String, ByVal nLineNum As Long) As String
        Dim sText As String, nI As Long, nJ As Long, sTemp As String

        On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        sText = ""
        nI = 1
        nJ = 1
        sTemp = ""
        While (nI <= Len(sDataText))
            Select Case Mid(sDataText, nI, 1)
                Case vbCr
                    If (nJ = nLineNum) Then
                        sText = sTemp
                    End If
                Case vbLf
                    nJ = nJ + 1
                    sTemp = ""
                Case Else
                    sTemp = sTemp & Mid(sDataText, nI, 1)
            End Select
            nI = nI + 1
        Wend
        If (nJ = nLineNum) Then
            sText = sTemp
        End If
        udf_ReadLine = sText

        Exit Function

    ErrHandler:
        udf_ReadLine = ""
    End Function
```

I just added a function to read line from a string, and you can keep using the LOF function as you wish, also all of the concept from your original code.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you had searched for your error you would have found the cause, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232640(v=vs.60).aspx.

Second, you need to do something to ensure there is anything in the file to read. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262732(v=vs.60).aspx

Finally, use a loop to read lines from the file. It appears you want the first line displayed in one label and the second line displayed in another. The code below reads one line at a time from the file, decides if it is reading an odd line number (first line) or even line number (second line) and displays the line in the label. After each line is read it looks for "a certain text" whatever that may be, and if found it exits the loop and closes the file.

```
Open "E:\Projects\VB\Ubunifu\MyList.txt" For Input As #1
Do While EOF(1) = False
    Line Input #1, strLine ' read one line at a time vs entire file
    lngLineNum = lngLineNum + 1 'Am I reading an odd or even line number
    If lngLineNum Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        lblCurrent.Caption = strLine
    Else
        lblO.Caption = strLine
    End If
    If InStr(1, strLine, "a cetain text", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Close #1
```

Note that I did not check that strLine contained anything before calling InStr. If it is empty the InStr function will cause an error. You should add some defensive coding. At the very least an error handler.

Comment: "First, if you had searched for your error you would have found the cause." Obviously, OP did not find or understand the "cause", if indeed found. Probably not good form to begin an answer with a reprimand.